# Will an NSLocalNotification Sound Play When the Phone is set to Silent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, nsnotifications, silent

Is it possible for an `NSLocalNotification` to play an audio file when the ringer switch is set to `OFF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  `NSLocalNotification` must adhere to the device's real world settings.